# Обязательно ли мне скачивать tensorflow?

Tags: windows

Я новичок. Я установил python and pycharm, мне обязательно устанавливать tensorflow? Подскажите, пожалуйста, потому что изучаю книгу Франсуа Шолле: там написано: keras и tensorflow. Обязательно?

Comment: Если планируете изучать keras и tensorflow, то лучше установить.  Но наверно попозже.